# jquery - get position of element relative to the viewport

Tags: jquery, offset, scrolltop

I am trying to detect when an element reaches the top the viewport. I have setup a variable to get the position of the element and another variable to get the actual scroll position of the window. I have then setup a condition which says if the scroll position equals the same value as the position of the element do something. it is getting all the value but does not seem to do anything once the condition is met:

```
  var element = $("#element").offset().top;
  var totalscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (totalscroll >= element) {
  alert('the element is at the top!');
```

Comment: Where's the code to check for the window scroll event? The code you posted does a one time check.

Comment: cool what would the line be for that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8uvp8/